# Replacing column values uniquely

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a column called Zone:

The values in the column are 'Zone 1', and '1', but when I try and use pandas replace, it replaces the value 1 in 'Zone 1' to 'Zone Zone 1', instead of only selecting the columns with '1' and replacing it to 'Zone 1'

Comment: Please show us your data. Then, show us your code. Explaining what you've done without showing either is not helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:
this basically says to replace any value with "zone1" if the original value was '1' else to leave the value as is.

```
df["Zone"]=["Zone1" if x=='1' else x for x in df["Zone"]]
```

Comment: Is there any way to use .replace() and not replace non-exact values?

Comment: .replace() should work also without errors, example: df = pd.DataFrame(['zone1','1'])
df=df.replace('1','zone1')
print(df), should give you: zone1,zone1
@user2205904